# batch script to create folder based on another folder name (music library

Tags: file, batch-file

I've been searching and trying to create a basic batch script that will create a folder for every album i have in a directory..
I can show an exemple of my library
[audio folder exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0v6Di.png)

I would like 
Artist1 - 1 /
Artist1 - 2 /
Artist1 - 3 /
Artist1 - ... /
Artist2 - 1 /
Artist2 - ... /
...

in an artist1, artist2, artist3... folder with the individual folder moved. It would be nice to have the copied artist name deleted too but it's not necessary.
It would be nice if it wasnt differentiating the non caps caracter from the caps too.

I have 3000 albums in a folder and it's a pain to edit manually. It would take me a lot of work to edit manually and maybe a batch file is more useful for future usage too.
I've seen file to folder batch and some other but i'm not sure to get how to edit them for my purpose.. 
**bulkrenameutility** looks nice but not sure it achieve what i need

EDIT 1 - 
I've seen something like this which looks nice. 
But i would like to be able to select a folder and not a file named .psd or .jpg

//////

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg) do (
   echo file found  %%A
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
pause
```

//////

Basicly it's doing this

//////

```
@echo off

:: Needed because you are working with variables that are immediately called
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Start of the loop to get all files with a psd or jpg Extension
for %%A in (*.psd *.jpg) do (
   echo file found  %%A

:: Grabs only the file name
   for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do set fname=%%~nB

:: Grabs only the extension
   for /f "delims=" %%C in ("%%A") do set fextn=%%~xC

:: Using the File name it separates it into 2 part using "_" as a delimiter so 120_low becomes 120 and low
   for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%D in ("!fname!") do set folname=%%D
   echo folder name !folname!

:: Checks for the existence of the folder, if the folder does not exist it creates the folder
   if not exist "!folname!" (
      echo Folder !folname! does not exist, creating
      md "!folname!"
   ) else (
      echo Folder !folname! exists
   )

:: Moves the file to the folder
   echo Moving file %%A to folder !folname!
   move "%%A" "!folname!"
   )
echo Finished
```

//////

https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=152980.0

Comment: Go for node.js script or php script for easiness.

Comment: Isnt something like http://multicommander.com/
More easy ? Not sure it can do what i think of but maybe there is an easier way than programming in node.js

Comment: It's a software, how you will send command to multicommander? I don't know much about multicommander, and if they are providing any script execution or macro.

Comment: You are right. In node.js it's easier to do than in batch ?

Comment: It's easier in programming language in which you have expertise , though node is easier and short and sweet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear. There are *a lot* of incomplete details. You should list **in the question** some of the input folders and the desired output with such an input. For example, with this input:

```
Abdulla Rashim - weldiya (2012)
Abdulla Rashim - Weldiya E.P. (WAV)
Abdulla Rashim - A Shell of Speed
Abdulla Rashim - Unanimity
```

Get this output:

```
Abdulla Rashim 
    weldiya (2012)
    Weldiya E.P. (WAV)
    A Shell of Speed
    Unanimity
```

**EDIT**: The specifications had changed accordingly to the following description:

The artist name is present in every current folder before the "-" *excepting the last character, that must be a space that will be removed*, and the album name is the part after the "-" *excepting the first character, that must be a space that will be removed*.

The Batch file below do that:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /AD /B') do (
   set "part1=%%a" & set "part1=!part1:~0,-1!"
   set "part2=%%b" & set "part2=!part2:~1!"
   if not exist "!part1!" md "!part1!"
   move "!part1! - !part2!" "!part1!\!part2!"
)
```

If you want clearer answers you should post much clearer questions...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. SInce i'm not really programming it's hard for me to see what could be missing in my question.
What you said is right thought. 
I want every album in a specific artist folder.
The artist name is present in every current folder before the "-"
I'm not sure what's missing because you answered exactly what i needed. At least i think you did.

Does your command :
1. create a folder from an album ex: Abdulla rashim - Album 1
2. add every other folder with the same name to this folder
3. rename the name of the newly copied folder to the album name only
?
Thanks

Comment: Well, in such a case I invite you to accept my answer selecting the green check mark and also upvote it! **`;)`**

Comment: I tried the command and it created the folders but it didnt moved the files into it.
How can i make it moove the files into the created folder and rename the folder while mooving it ?

Comment: The problem is a _detail_: You said that _The artist name is present in every current folder before the "-"_, but the last character in this part is _a space_ and a folder name can not end in space. The same point apply to the first character of second part. I fixed the code accordingly to this _new specification_, but you must be aware that this program will fail if any folder have a "-" separator with more or less spaces than _one space precisely_...

Comment: Wow thanks a lot. Was it hard for you to do ? Is it time consuming to learn ?
It's amazing. Thanks again

Comment: Do you think you could explain what every line does ? If not no worries i'll take time myself to learn about it :)

Comment: Well, if you want more from me you should give me something first! (hint: accept answer and upvote it). **`;)`**

Comment: Yes i can paypal you a beer or smtg if you want. Or send you crypto for the help :D